# Is it proper in Islam to down vote instead of reply?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

Assalamu'alaikum,

We all know that Islam is supposed to have answer for our lives, and also what we learn from Rasululah s.a.w is to bring it with the best of character.

From what I notice in this website is that some questions get down voted instead of receiving an answer. Alhamdulillah that some answered. Isn't it rude if we down vote without telling the person why at least? We all started with no knowledge, and most of the times, we don't know the background of people here. We might be helping people a great deal without even knowing. 
Isn't it wrong that we assume stuffs about others? I don't think I need to quote the verses from the Quran.

Some people only upvote controversial questions or "hot" questions. If you guys don't believe me go and see the questions with the highest votes. Of course I don't believe this represents the community, but instead of highlighting much important issues like the basis of our ibadah "some" people are down voting them. I don't care if they ignore the questions, and eventually some good hearted muslims would answer it. But to down vote legit/important questions is something that needs supervision.

With that in thought, and since I hope the main question will get an answer. I wont be hanging around this community unfortunately. I hope negative people wont be attracted to this post, I hope some of the muslims in this community can at least be like non-muslims on other stackexchange communities. May Allah guide us and increase us in knowledge that benefits us.

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion, the issue of downvoting w/out comments can be broken down into three cases

1. Downvoting for self-obvious reasons; a troll post for example, that requires no further explanation. Rude, offensive and inappropriate language is self-obvious and needs no further elaboration. Though in border line cases it may still be better to post an explanation.
2. Downvoting an answer for a reason that has already has pointed out in comments. Adding any additional comments would only clutter the comment-space and rehash what has already been said.
3. Downvoting an answer but finding no existing comment that you can concur with. In that case I think its rude not to add a comment.

I agree that a lot of downvoting simply reflects a dogmatic, lazy and intolerant mindset, sometimes even sectarian biasedness. When downvoting becomes a matter of whether "I like or disklike" an opinion for subjective reasons it doesn't contribute much.

Comment: Useful elaboration! In 2, one can up vote an already written comment.

Answer (score 2):

Uh-huh, actually your question can be considered as a constructive question which probably and commonly it would be happened daily in the site and even in other similar sites. But there could be some points or reasons for down-voting in this way (as I can infer from the site and users)

- Being against the belief or opinion of the voters.
- Being tired or not being in the mood to provide an answer or comment for their negative votes.
- Being in attempt to destroy the rival user(s) by down-voting… , but they prefer to be unknown …
- And so on

Of course you are right, and this is better to write at least a short comment for Down-Voting. I assume it would be Okay if you down-vote somebody’s answer (or question) if you deserve him/her for down-voting, and actually (by down-voting) you will inform him or her that there could be a negative point in the answer, then probably he or she will edit that. Although as I mentioned before, at least leaving a comment for down-voting would be more helpful and I agree with you that from the view of Islam: it would be better at least to leave a comment and explain why you have given -1 for the question or answer in order to make them aware of their problems. Otherwise it wouldn’t be OK from the viewpoint of Islam to give -1 vote unfairly.